# How do I combine two different row string values into a single new row value?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, row, operation

I have two rows of a dataframe likeso:

```
   Jan  Feb
a   1    3
b   2    4
```

I want to create a new dataframe row that combines the two rows (by name because I have to do this for multiple sets of rows of the df) into one row like this:

```
   Jan  Feb
a   1    3
b   2    4  
c  1/2  3/4
```

And I do not mean just division as the data types of the actual values are string, I want to concatenate. I feel like there has to be an obvious solution but nothing I have found online is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.loc['c', :] = df.apply(lambda x: f"{x[0]}/{x[1]}")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Jan  Feb
a  1.0  3.0
b  2.0  4.0
c  1/2  3/4
```

Comment: Accepting this answer as it accounts for the fact that I want to specify the rows to concatenate and doesn't apply to the whole dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the strings by first converting the values to strings and then combining them with the + operator.

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'Jan': [1, 2], 'Feb': [3, 4]}, index=['a', 'b'])    
df.loc['c'] =df.loc['a'].astype(str) + '/' + df.loc['b'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
df.loc['c', :] = df.apply(lambda x: '/'.join(map(str,x)))
```

Ouput:

```
   Jan  Feb
a  1.0  3.0
b  2.0  4.0
c  1/2  3/4
```

Comment: This works but it applies to every row in the dataframe, so I have rows c, d, and e as well and I want the result to only have rows a and b concatenated

Comment: Is there a way to limit it to just two rows? I can make it so that I do it separately for each set of rows before I create the larger dataframe but if there is a way to go back and avoid changing/rearranging my existing code that would be preferable

Comment: I think for your goal the answer of l'mahdi suits you better. Mine just considers all values (which becomes handy if the df has lots of rows and you want them all to be concatenated

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: (option without loc, don't meen it's better)

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['a'] + '/' + x['b'], axis=1)
df.set_index('name', inplace=True)
df = df.transpose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```py
def concat_rows(df,idx,sep="/"):
    return [sep.join(l) for l in df.loc[idx].values]

df.loc["new_row"] = concat_rows(df,["a","b"],sep="/")
```

**Explanation:**

This function allows you to choose the rows to concat and the separator between strings.

Args:

*df:* pandas dataframe

*idx:* list of index of rows to concat. Example: ["a","b"]

*sep:* separator between strings. Default = "/"

**RESULT:**

```
         JAN    FEB
a          1     3
b          2     4
new_row   1/3   2/4
```